# How was it possible to beat a soldier with a full plate armor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

From my point of view, it seems that a soldier armed with a **full metal plate armor** was almost invulnerable at the time their opponents yielded swords, spears or bows. I understand that it couldn't be the case, but I'm not sure about the physics behind it.

More specifically:

1. How could an archer beat this soldier? An arrow shooted with full power would have enough kinetic energy to penetrate it?
2. How could a swordsman or a spearman beat this soldier? Would the impact of these weapons suffice?
3. Just out of curiosity, a modern gun would penetrate into the plates that easily? One headshot would do?

I'm thinking on a soldier wearing an armor like this one below, or even  bulkier.

[image: Italian suit of Armor, c.1450][1]

[1] Courtesy of Wikipedia

Comment: Welcome to Engineering.SE. As this question is stated now, it it pretty much a history question. Is there is some specific aspect of the strength of plate armor that you have a question about?

Comment: Thanks. I would say it is not related to history, because I'm asking about the mechanic aspect of this armor against other weapons. They have already denied this question on the Physics forum, stating that this is an applied engineering type of question.

Comment: I agree with the others that this is not an engineering question in its current format. If you want to know what kind of force or arrow speed are necessary to penetrate the armor or cause significant bodily harm beneath the armor, we might be able to answer that. However, it looks more like you're interested in how enemies dealt with this kind of armor, and that's definitely more of a military history topic.

Answer (score 2):

In response to plate armor, a variety of anti-armor weapons and techniques have emerged.  Different concepts were employed:

- Hammers and maces that can give a concussion without penetrating the armor.
- Spikes that concentrate pressure at one point and thus pierce.
- Stabbing between the plates of the armor.

Some weapons combined multiple approaches.  For example, [war hammers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hammer) often had a non-penetrating side for giving concussion and a spike for penetration.

Answer (score 0):

> An arrow shooted with full power would have enough kinetic energy to penetrate it?

Heavy crossbows could penetrate even heavy plate armor.  Longbows could penetrate some lighter plate mail.  [This site](http://indie-rpgs.com/archive/index.php?topic=10676.0) states that the church banned crossbows in medieval battle since they were so lethally effective.

The physics behind it comes down to simple pressure.  You have an arrow or a bolt with a certain mass, traveling at a certain speed.  All of the kinetic energy of the projectile is concentrated on the razor tip.  Once the pressure at the tip exceeds the strength of the metal, you get penetration.  There is some balance of kinetic energy with the plate mail rebounding from the impact, but that might be a little beyond the scope of this discussion.

> How could a swordsman or a spearman beat this soldier? Would the impact of these weapons suffice?

The weak point of any suit of armor is the joints.  This is where a knight was most vulnerable.  Lots of suits of armor had the joints reinforced with chainmail, leather, and little targa-like shields (like the circular things on your knight's armpit area).

A heavy enough swing could dent armor, which could then impede movement of that part of the body.  Do it enough times, and you effectively cripple your opponent or render him unable to fight back.

This may not be historically accurate, but if you want an example of how a spearman would beat a knight, watch the [Oberyn Martel vs. The Mountain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqT22PlqnUA) duel from Game of Thrones.  The same would apply for a swordsman.

> Just out of curiosity, a modern gun would penetrate into the plates that easily? One headshot would do?

Modern guns would have no issue with plate mail.  The advent of black powder weapons is the reason that plate mail was abandoned.  Have a read through [this thread](http://www.thehighroad.org/archive/index.php/t-454655.html) for further information.

Comment: You don't need high technology to knock a knight in plate armor off a horse. A wooden pole (a.k.a. a lance) will do nicely. By the time he got himself vertical, he was either dead or captured.

Answer (score 0):

History for centuries past always depends on who writes it, and the Engineering behind the history is thus somewhat a matter of conjecture, but:

The English Longbow and "Clothyard shaft" are said by many to be the "high tech" weapons system that won them the Battle of Agincourt against the French. In simplistic terms, the longbow shafts could penetrate French plate armour far enough away to protect the front line of both English Noblemen, foot soldiers and pike bearers while the front line protected the bowmen.

The detail is both far far more complex, and open to much discussion, but the summary is "good enough". By itself the longbow almost certainly have been enough to swing the balance at Agincourt, but they were greatly helped by a complete lack of sensible behaviour by their opponents due to the concepts of Chivalry, societal position and, as often, the lure of wealth. Rather than me trying to explain how that makes sense - here's what some sources say.

**From Wikipedia Longbow - see below:**

> Archery was described by contemporaries as ineffective against plate armour in the Battle of Neville's Cross (1346), the siege of Bergerac (1345), and the Battle of Poitiers (1356); such armour became available to European knights of fairly modest means by the late 14th century, though never to all soldiers in any army. Longbowmen were however effective at Poitiers, and this success stimulated changes in armour manufacture partly intended to make armoured men less vulnerable to archery. Nevertheless, at the battle of Agincourt in 1415 and for some decades thereafter, English longbowmen continued to be an effective battleﬁeld force.[34]

[**Wikipedia - Battle of Agincourt**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Agincourt) - a nicely detailed account with discussion of the uncertainties this far after the event and a good general impression.

[**Wikipedia - English longbow**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_longbow) - good discussion good detail. Good section on armour penetration, modern simulations and pros and cons

> In an early modern test by Saxton Pope, a direct hit from a steel bodkin point penetrated Damascus mail armour.[28][29]
>
> A 2006 test was made by Matheus Bane using a 75 lbf (330 N) draw (at 28") bow, shooting at 10 yards; according to Bane's calculations,
>   this would be approximately equivalent to a 110 lbf (490 N) bow at 250 yards.[30]
>
> Measured against a replica of the thinnest contemporary "Jack coat" armour, a 905 grain needle bodkin and a 935 grain curved broadhead penetrated over 3.5 inches (89 mm). ("Jack coat" armour could be up to twice as thick as the coat tested; in Bane's opinion such a thick coat would have stopped bodkin arrows but not the cutting force of broadhead arrows.)
>
> Against "high quality riveted maille", the needle bodkin and curved broadhead penetrated 2.8".
>   Against a coat of plates, the needle bodkin achieved 0.3" penetration.
>   The curved broadhead did not penetrate but caused 0.3" of deformation of the metal.
>   Results against plate armour of "minimum thickness" (1.2mm) were similar to the coat of plates, in that the needle bodkin penetrated to a shallow depth, the other arrows not at all.
>   In Bane's view, the plate armour would have kept out all the arrows if thicker or worn with more padding.
>
> Other modern tests described by Bane include those by Williams (which concluded that longbows could not penetrate mail, but in Bane's view did not use a realistic arrow tip), Robert Hardy's tests (which achieved broadly similar results to Bane), and a Primitive Archer test which demonstrated that a longbow could penetrate a plate armour breastplate. However, the Primitive Archer test used a 160 lbf (710 N) longbow at very short range, generating 160 joules (vs. 73 for Bane and 80 for Williams), so probably not representative of battles of the time.

The Telegraph [10 reasons why the French lost](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/8648068/Battle-of-Agincourt-ten-reasons-why-the-French-lost.html)

Longbow Archers site - [Agincourt page](http://www.longbow-archers.com/historyagincourt.html)

You tube documentary 1h12m - looks good 
[The Battle of Agincourt : The Bloodiest Battle of the Medieval Age](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWmM-jyE338)

6m video reenactment - [Agincourt - Henry V version](https://www.awesomestories.com/asset/view/English-Longbow-Battle-Scene-at-Agincourt-)

[Steven Whetan says ...](http://kingjohnshouse.org.uk/the-longbow-and-its-impact-on-the-battle-of-agincourt/)

All the usual [obligatory pictures](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=longbow+agincourt&biw=1422&bih=1041&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CFgQsARqFQoTCPKin7Xdp8cCFSHYpgod1fcLGQ&dpr=0.9#tbm=isch&q=%2Blongbow+%2Bagincourt) most of which link to perhaps relevant pages. Agh. Wow.